# Why does ::TableView.model return nilClass when Nokogiri is used?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, qtableview, qcombobox, qstandarditemmodel

**EDIT**

The problem was with something else so the trouble wasn't really Qt, still I don't know why this happened.

The thing was that in the method `display_filesize @yt.get_filesize(row_id, format)` I used Nokogiri to parse the XML. I don't know if the XML was corrupted (it was loaded from `quvi`), but it was definitely the culprit. After switching to XMLSimple everything works fine.

The code I used:

```
def get_filesize(video_id, format)
  video = @videos[video_id]

  if video.formats[format].empty?
    to_parse = `quvi --xml --format #{format} #{video.player_url}`
    parsed = Nokogiri.parse(to_parse)
    video.formats[format] = { :size => parsed.at('length_bytes').text, 
                              :url => parsed.at('link').at('url').text }
  end
  video.formats[format][:size]
end
```

Now I use something like this:

```
def get_filesize(video_id, format)
  video = @videos[video_id]

  if video.formats[format].empty?
    to_parse = `quvi --xml --format #{format} #{video.player_url}`
    parsed = XmlSimple.xml_in(to_parse, {'KeyAttr' => 'name'})

    video.formats[format] = { :size => parsed['link'][0]['length_bytes'][0],
                              :url => URI.decode(parsed['link'][0]['url'][0]) }
  end

  video.formats[format][:size]
end
```

It works beautifully. Still, I don't know why it crashed. This is the real question.

---

**OLD QUESTION**

I have a `Qt::TableView` that contains `Qt::StandardItemModel`. A row in the model consists of text, `Qt::PushButton`, checkbox and `Qt::ComboBox`. It works like this:

1. The user is presented with text values and can explore further if they want to.
2. The user clicks `Qt::PushButton` and the next cell is populated with a `Qt::ComboBox` containing other possible values to choose from.
3. If the user chooses an option from `Qt::ComboBox`, magic happens, objects get created, hashes populated and the cell on the right gets populated with appropriate text (through a `Qt::StandardItem`)
4. Then the checkbox can be checked.
5. After selecting the rows the user wants, a `Qt::PushButton` located outside of the `Qt::TableView` can be clicked. It then iterates through the model, tests if the checkbox is selected and should it be, tries to access the value in the appropriate `ComboBox`.

The problem is, when I insert code that tries to access the `Qt::ComboBox,` I can't insert the `Qt::StandardItem`, because I can't get the model, because `Qt::TableView.model` returns `NilClass` (at some point).

I don't know why and how this happens. It's a random thing, sometimes the value of `Qt::ComboBox` can be changed a couple times, sometimes the first try ends with an error.

Here is how I create the `Qt::StandardItem`:

```
def display_filesize
  row_id = row_id_from_object_name(sender.objectName)
  format = sender.currentText

  filesize = @yt.get_filesize(row_id, format) # get the text
  filesize_item = Qt::StandardItem.new("#{(filesize.to_i/1024/1024)} MB ")

  # @tc simply stores the indexes of columns so I can access them easily
  @ui.tableView.model.setItem(row_id, @tc[:filesize], filesize_item) 
end
```

And here is how I try to access the `Qt::ComboBox` value:

```
model = @ui.tableView.model

checked = model.rowCount.times.map do |i|
  if model.item(i, @tc[:check]).checkState == Qt::Checked
    # if I remove the following two lines it works...
    index = model.index(i, @tc[:formats])
    format = @ui.tableView.indexWidget(index).currentText
    @yt.videos[i][format]
  end
end
```

And this is the error I am trying to get rid of:

```
searcher.rb:86:in `display_filesize': undefined method `index' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/qtbindings-4.8.3.0/lib/Qt/qtruby4.rb:469:in `qt_metacall'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/qtbindings-4.8.3.0/lib/Qt/qtruby4.rb:469:in `method_missing'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/qtbindings-4.8.3.0/lib/Qt/qtruby4.rb:469:in `exec'
  from qutub-player.rb:17:in `<main>'
```

Comment: You don't show any XML, so how can we even try to answer your question? Nokogiri makes it easy to tell if the XML has a problem; Simply check `parsed.errors` after parsing and see if it's empty or has content. Use `Nokogiri.XML(...)` to parse XML. Relying on `parsed = Nokogiri.parse(to_parse)` can result in parsing as HTML if Nokogiri finds a "html" tag at the top of the document. That'll result in bad results as you search.

Comment: It is not very related, but I've released quvi bindings for ruby, and it is possible to cut the corner, and do not use XML. https://rubygems.org/gems/quvi